# Symfony2 how to generate a form for an entity with a select and empty value?

Tags: forms, symfony, entity

I search, I search but I don't find...

I've got an entity Agent and an entity Gender, in Entity/Agent.php :

```
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AcNice\ASPBundle\Entity\Gender")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
   */
  private $gender;
```

Gender can be null.
In Form/AgentType.php, I've got :

```
$builder
  ->add('gender',              'entity',   array(
      "class" => "AcNiceASPBundle:Gender",
      "property" => "name",
      'empty_value' => "Choose your gender",
      //"empty_data" => null,
      'required' => false,
      "expanded" => false))
```

I've read the doc http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html, I see if I change "expanded" to true, I've got my "Choose your gender" as checkbox, but I really want a select (for entities nullable with much more choices).

Does someone have a clue ? Pleaaaaase ;-)
Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question, this code should work as you expected

Comment: As default value of expanded and multiple options is false, and accorded to [this table](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#select-tag-checkboxes-or-radio-buttons), the code you've provided will allow to create a select box with an empty value "Choose your gender".

Comment: My code didn't work : I've got a select whith only Male, Female. No trace of "Choose your gender". If I change expanded to true, I've got three checkbox "Choose your gender", "Male", "Female"...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using version >= Symfony 2.6, you should use `placeholder` option instead of `empty_value`.